# NodeJS cache mysql data whith clustering enabled

Tags: mysql, node.js, synchronization

I want to cache data that I got from my MySQL DB and for this I am currently storing the data in an object.

Before querying the database, I check if the needed data exists in the meantioned object or not. If not, I will query and insert it.

This works quiet well and my webserver is now just fetching the data once and reuses it.

My concern is now: Do I have to think of concurrent writes/reads for such data structures that lay in the object, when using nodejs's clustering feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single line of JavaScript that you write on your Node.js program is thread-safe, so to speak - at any given time, only a single statement is ever executed. The fact that you can do async operations is only implemented at a low level implementation that is completely transparent to the programmer. To be precise, you can only run some code in a "truly parallel" way when you do some input/output operation, i.e. reading a file, doing TCP/UDP communication or when you spawn a child process. And even then, the only code that is executed in parallel to your application is that of Node's native C/C++ code.

Since you use a JavaScript object as a cache store, you are guaranteed no one will ever read or write from/to it at the same time.

As for [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), every worker is created its own process and thus has its own version of every JavaScript variable or object that exists in your code.

Comment: Thank you, the link was very helpful :) Should have looked at the docu directly, sorry :)